# Show that $A\to B\lor C$ is a logical consequence of $A\to B$ and $B\lor D\to C$ using logical inference

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm struggling with how to solve the following task:

"Show that A → B ∨ C is a logical consequence of A → B and B ∨ D → C using logical inference".

I understand the basics of logical inference but only when the end result is supposed to be one single value (i.e. Q or P only). What I've done so far is write down the premises as:

1. A → B
2. B ∨ D → C

as well as written that the end result should be:

A => B ∨ C

but am clueless on how to proceed from here. For premise one, it is assumed true. Using a logic table this could mean that either A is true and B is true or A is false and B is either true or false. But does it work the same way when you try to solve using logical inference? Or am I to assume that A is true and hence I can draw that conclusion from (1)?

How do I proceed from here? I've looked around the internet and through my textbook for similar examples, but none of the examples provided looks like this one hence I am unsure on how to solve it. Any guidance is highly appriciated.

Edit:

One potential process that I've been working on is but decided to leave out as I thought it to be completely wrong is the following:

1. A → B - Premise.
2. B ∨ D → C - Premise.
3. A - Conditional proof assumption.
4. B  - From (1) and (3).
5. B ∨ D - From (2) and (4).
6. C - From (2) and (5).
7. A → B ∨ C - From (3), (4) and (6).

How off base am I in this situation?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Hello. I am unsure on how I could make the title more descriptive.

Comment: See my edit . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to show that if $A$, then $B$ or $C$.

So assume $A$ is true. By hypothesis ($A \implies B$), $B$ is also true. Now, $B$ being true of course implies that $B \lor C$ is true. Thus, if $A$ is true, then $B \lor C$ is true, as desired.

Note that we do not have to use the second fact $B \lor D \implies C$ to prove this.

Comment: Ah. Very good explanation. Regarding my own attempt, is it completely wrong then or would it also work although in a more roundabout, more convoluted, way? Thank you for the response!

Comment: No problem. Your solution is fine, even though (2), (5), and (6) are not actually necessary to show the desired implication. A small comment is that (5) follows immediately from (4) ((2) is not needed until (6)).